# Can i access all events in eventContent() to filter and add custom logic?

Tags: fullcalendar, vuejs3

I need to make some logic in `eventContent()`, but I need to resolve all events for that day (any day) and if the array length is greater than 2 then add an extra element or console.log something (just for trying).
I know Full Calendar default's `dayMaxEvents` and `dayMaxEventRows` make it but it doesn't apply to my context. Why? I'm not using events as a  text rows, instead, I'm passing thumbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there isn't a easy way to achieve it. Solution: used `dayMaxEvents` default option and play with CSS to get the desired results.